# SharePoint 2010 VHD for VMWare

Tags: virtual-machine, evaluation

Is there an evaluation VHD that can be used for VMWare, as opposed to Hyper-V?

[This package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=751fa0d1-356c-4002-9c60-d539896c66ce&displaylang=en) appears to be targeted to Hyper-V.

Is it usable for VMWare as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to use it on Hyper-V, there's a couple of ways you can go:

- convert it over the VMware's VMDK format. I've heard of people who have done so successfully, but then I've also seen some comments where issues have arisen in those converted VMs. My take is that if you have a short term need for the VM, converting it is not a bad way to go but I don't know that I'd be comfortable with it if the chips were down and I absolutely had to have it work.
- Get VirtualBox and run the VM in it without converting it. VirtualBox can run VMs in both the Hyper-V and VMware formats, so you'll be able to use it without conversion. VirtualBox may not be as fully featured Hyper-V or VMware, but it can be pretty handy and the fact that its free doesn't hurt either

John

Comment: Thanks.  I can't comment on the VMWare option, as I went with VirtualBox instead.  This seems to work fine, with one caveat - as detailed in this link: http://ollysense.blogspot.com/2010/05/virtualbox-using-hyper-v-vhd-image.html.

Comment: For VMware users, the tool for converting from other formats is [vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/).

Comment: I've been running the IW machine on VMWare for a year now without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

John's suggestions are right on.

Here's another option:

There is a free service (with registration) from CloudShare that gives you access to remote into an instance of that image for free. It only maintains state for 24 hours before you'd have to create a new instance from the snapshot, but it can be really helpful and avoid using your hardware resources.
It's the first link on this page:
http://www.cloudshare.com/Products/CloudShare-ProPlus/solution-showcase.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully converted it to VMware Workstation. More details on my blog
[Using VMware Workstation to Run the 2010 Information Worker Virtual Machines](http://jimboalba.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/using-vmware-workstation-to-run-the-2010-information-worker-virtual-machines/)